# Read large text file without read it into RAM at once

Tags: python, file

I have a large text file and it's 2GB or more. Of course I shouldn't use `read()`.

I think use `readline()` maybe is a way, but I don't know how to stop the loop at the end of the file.

I've tried this:

```
with open('test', 'r') as f:
    while True:
        try:
            f.readline()
        except:
            break
```

But when the file is at end, the loop won't stop and will keep print empty string (`''`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

End of File is defined as an empty string returned by `readline`. Note that an actual empty line, like every line returned by `readline` ends with the line separator.

```
with open('test', 'r') as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if line == "":
            break
```

But then again, a file object in python is already iterable.

```
with open('test', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.strip())
```

`strip` removes whitespace, including the newline, so you don't print double newlines.

And if you don't like it safe, and want the least code possible:

```
for l in open("text"): print(l.strip())
```

EDIT: `strip` removes all kind of whitespaces from both sides. If you actually just want to get rid of ending newlines, you can use `rstrip("\n")`

Comment: I didn't know that the new lines were added into the reading of the line. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a for statement instead of a while statement. You could do something like

```
for line in f.readlines()
    print(line)
```

Might help.

Comment: I think that this will read the file at once and can't read the large file.